# Add post permalink to suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

The suggested-edits dashboard/permalink does not contain any link to the permalink of the post that is being asked to review upon.

[image]

Having a link to the post will give some background on whether the suggested edit can be approved or not.

Comment: Hrm...I had permalinks to the questions via the question title when I was looking at it recently; I also saw side-by-side diff options that aren't in your screenshot.

Comment: @Phrogz Indeed, the various diff options were not shown either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does -- the title is the link itself.

It's just obscured by the diff in this case, but it is clickable. I confirmed this on ask ubuntu just now.

(and if you need a link to the edit suggestion, that is the little link icon in the left column)

Comment: @JeffAtwoood Indeed, the diff on URLs obscured the fact they were links & that got me confused