# Anonymous "Suggested Edit" views do not link to the posts themselves

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty titles in new answers to questions more than 30 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110762/empty-titles-in-new-answers-to-questions-more-than-30-days-old)

Some suggested edits don't really show a link to the actual post they've been proposed on.

Examples:

- https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/6337
- https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/6326

**How do I get to the actual question/answer context?** Isn't there supposed to be at least a linked title of the question, as per [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78228/add-post-permalink-to-suggested-edits)?

There's no link whatsoever. In fact, some entries in [`/tools/suggested-edits`](https://superuser.com/tools/suggested-edits) link to the post, others don't. When I click "approved" or "rejected" on those, I can't see a link.

[image]

I think something's wrong there: There should always be a way of getting to the post itself. I think the pattern is that edits suggested by **anonymous** don't have that link, whereas it works on all others.

Comment: +1 - I have to say, I just rejected 3-4 edits from a user trying to spam a product, and, I had trouble trying to locate the actual question it was proposed on.. The whole UI isn't really that easy to use/understand imho.

Comment: Thanks; fixing now (same bug as affected a number of areas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my fault - missed a title render case during a refactor.  It will be deployed shortly.